# node multiple event handler, but only one should consume the event

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I am trying to build a node service which has multiple custom event handlers. A REST service emits an event. Now the tricky part. Only one handler should consume the event and process it. The others should ignore the event. Which handler is serving the event does not matter at all.

Comment: Is there a shared state that all the handlers can read from? If so you can implement a `semaphore`.

Comment: @nilobarp https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore should be great for this purpose. I will build a stacklike work queue with a semaphore. Great answer!